# Android UI designer in Android Studio

Tags: android, user-interface

When working with a relative layout, any widgets I placed on the screen would automatically 'align' based on the layout I was using.  Suddenly, the designer is allowing me to place and widget anywhere I want.  What did I do to cause this to happen?

Comment: I suppose you are able to drag the widgets any where you want is due to `Relative Layout`. But, for a `Linear Layout`, It would automatically align in an order. You can't drag or move the widgets wherever you want in the latter case.

Comment: DOn't use the layout designer drag and drop.  You're only setting yourself up for pain.  Learn how to write xml and do that-  then you know what it's actually doing.